# Delete special character from a string value

Tags: r

I have such a value:

```
" 0.67564;"
```

and I want to delete `;` and only have the double value. how can I do it in r?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a <- " 0.67564;"
gsub(';', '', a)
[1] " 0.67564"
```

To get a numeric representation:

```
as.numeric(gsub(';', '', a))
[1] 0.67564
```

Comment: What object are you using as `a`?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^[:alnum:]///' ]", "", " 0.67564;"))
```

Can also be done using `regex`

`[^[:alnum:]]` is preferred to `[^0-9A-Za-z]`. `?regex` says "because their interpretation is locale- and implementation-dependent, they are best avoided." and "For example, `[[:alnum:]]`means `[0-9A-Za-z]`, except the latter depends upon the locale and the character encoding, whereas the former is independent of locale and character set

Answer (score 0):

parseFloat() will return exactly what you need

Comment: Hmm... my bad. but my search doesn't have this tag.